# How can I change the background of a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, background, replace

This is the situation:

I have a blog with several posts. Each post has images inside of it.
With jQuery I am alreay wrapping the first image of each post so I can give it a unique styling.

Next to the styling I would also like to grab the first image of a post and use it as the header. The header already has a background so it should be replaced by, indeed, the first image of a post.

```
if ($("body").is("#permalink") && $(".imgwrapper").length>0) {
var firstImage = $(".imgwrapper").attr('src')
  $('#header-bg').css('background-image', "url(" + firstImage + ")")

}
```

Somehow the above code is not working and is giving me the following error in the console:
resource interpreted as image but transferred with mime type text/html

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you add a snippet in http://jsfiddle.net/ for example? It will be helpful to make some tests.

Comment: Definitely need the HTML for that. I think you are using `.imgwrapper` as a selector and this is not the `img` ?

Comment: In `$(".imgwrapper").length>0` the `>0` is unnecessary as JS evaluates positive integers as 'true'. `if ($("body").is("#permalink") && $(".imgwrapper").length` will have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad Alfy for giving me the solution! This was indeed the problem, how stupid of me.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Zk8G/

HTML

```
<div class="imgwrapper">
<img src="" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var firstImage="http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/img/3478c54721cd466fb6f7d3afe16e97d4.gif";  
$( "<img/>" ).attr( "src", firstImage ).appendTo( ".imgwrapper" );
```

Comment: I have been working a lot lately with $.getJSON and the example there is very similar for images.  FYI

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the value of `firstImage`. If the URL returned as expected by you. There is nothing wrong in the code.

> "resource interpreted as image but transferred with mime type text/html"

The Content-Type (response header) is set as `text/html` for the image URL (`firstName`). But, as we include that url in background image, browser expects the URL to return an image (content-type: image/*).

Browser will automatically interpret and display it as image. If you got broken image, open the image url in new tab and check the content. It might return some HTML content itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("body").is("#permalink") && $(".imgwrapper").length>0) {
var firstImage = $(".imgwrapper").attr('src');
$('#header-bg').css('background-image', "url(" + firstImage + ")");

}
```

Is that because you are missing ";"

Comment: Although better syntax, this would not make a difference in this case.

Comment: @leonidus the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `url()` part in the `css` property. Try this:

```
if ($("body").is("#permalink") && $(".imgwrapper").length > 0) {
    $('#header-bg').css('background-image', $(".imgwrapper").attr('src'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, Still thanks for all the help and thinking along!
This worked:

```
if ($("body").is("#permalink") && $(".imgwrapper").length>0) {
  var firstImage = $(".imgwrapper img").attr('src')
  $('#header-bg').css('background-image', "url(" + firstImage + ")")

}
```

The mistake I made here was that I did not target the image but the wrapper only.